# Searching in xml document using xslt at runtime

Tags: xml, xslt, wsdl

Lets say I have an WSDL file like this:

```
<definitions>
    <binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
           <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>
           <input>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
           </input>
           <output>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
           </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <service name="StockQuoteService">
        <documentation>My first service</documentation>
        <port name="StockQuotePort" binding="tns:StockQuoteBinding">
           <soap:address location="http://example.com/stockquote"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I have my xslt like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="definitions/service">
</xsl:for-each>
```

which can find all the `service` in the wsdl. However I want to find the bindings of each service. How can I do that?

For example in this case, for  the service `StockQuoteService`, the binding I need to find is this node (after removing the `tns` in the attribute):

```
<binding name="StockQuoteSoapBinding" type="tns:StockQuotePortType">
            <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
            <operation name="GetLastTradePrice">
               <soap:operation soapAction="http://example.com/GetLastTradePrice"/>
               <input>
                   <soap:body use="literal"/>
               </input>
               <output>
                   <soap:body use="literal"/>
               </output>
            </operation>
        </binding>
```

how can I do this in xslt?

Comment: One serious problem is that the `@binding` in your service, which is `StockQuoteBinding`(without 'tns:'), does not match the `@name` of your `<binding...>` with the value of `StockQuoteSoapBinding`. How do you want to handle that? Insert the `Soap` before 'Binding'?

Comment: Can't we remove the `tns` and then do the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
<xsl:template match="/definitions/service">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />

    <xsl:copy-of  
        select="/definitions/binding[substring-after($this/port/@binding,':') = 
                                     concat(substring-before(@name,'Soap'),'Binding')]" />
</xsl:template>
```